# Is there a way to query if a WebView is scrollable?

Tags: flutter

I am using a `PreloadPageView` to display `WebView`s whose content vary in length. I would like to be able to inform the user when there is more content below on `WebView`s which are scrollable. I have played around with the controller scroll methods and with some JS evaluations, but to no avail. Wish there was a `controller.isScrollable()` method!

Comment: Can you access the WebView's DOM? If so, compare `document.body.scrollHeight` to `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: Unfortunately those are both returning the same value regardless of whether or not it is scrollable.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible - unless it's a descendant element of the page that is actually scrolling. Please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DOM height.

Call this in the webview' s `onLoadStop` function:

```
controller
  .evaluateJavascript(source: '''(() => { return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;})()''')
  .then((scrollHeight) {
    final widgetHeight = _webViewKey.currentContext?.size?.height ?? 0;
    // compare scrollHeight to widgetHeight
  });
```